# show php json data into jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm very new in this topic.I have a Json result something like this :

```
{
    "span": " 1",
    "numcard": "12",
    "chan": " Yes",        
    "idle": "Yes",
    "level": "idle ",
    "call": "No ",
    "name": ""
}
```

How can I show all the json data using a ajax .I currently have this code written up and although i am getting the data its not quite working the way i want it to be.

```
$("a[name=cardNo1]").click(function() {
    var cardNo1 = $(this).attr("id");
    $("a[name=cardNo1]").each(function() {
        cardNo1 += "";
    });

    var dataString = "action=spanchan" + "&cardNo=" + cardNo1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dahdiprocess.php?",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (data != "") {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $("#span").val(val.span);
                    $("#numcard").val(val.numcard);
                    $("#chan").val(val.chan);
                    $("#idle").val(val.idle);
                    $("#level").val(val.level);
                    $("#call").val(val.call);
                    $("#name").val(val.name);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="span" name="span" value="" />
<input id="numcard" name="numcard" value="" />
<input id="chan" name="chan" value="" />
<input id="idle" name="idle" value="" />
<input id="level" name="level" value="" />
<input id="call" name="call" value="" />
<input id="name" name="name" value="" />
```

when I try to alert ,example `alert(val.span)` it keep showing undifined .Does anyone with experience in this topic and see if any problem about my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you .

Comment: try to move it out of the each, because you're now looping through it. so now key is `span` and val is `1`, just replace every `val` with `data` and move it out of the `$.each`

Comment: Why do you need the $.each ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a single set of values so you do not need the `each` within your success handler. Try this:

```
success: function(data, status) {
    if (data != "") {
        $("#span").val(data.span);
        $("#numcard").val(data.numcard);
        $("#chan").val(data.chan);
        $("#idle").val(data.idle);
        $("#level").val(data.level);
        $("#call").val(data.call);
        $("#name").val(data.name);
    }
}
```

In theory, you shouldn't need the `data != ""` check as your server side code should not be allowed to return an empty response for when the result of the request is `200 OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a[name=cardNo1]").click(function() {
    var cardNo1 = $(this).attr("id");
    $("a[name=cardNo1]").each(function() {
        cardNo1 += "";
    });

    var dataString = "action=spanchan" + "&cardNo=" + cardNo1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dahdiprocess.php?",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (data != "") {
                    $("#span").val(data.span);
                    $("#numcard").val(data.numcard);
                    $("#chan").val(data.chan);
                    $("#idle").val(data.idle);
                    $("#level").val(data.level);
                    $("#call").val(data.call);
                    $("#name").val(data.name);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
            if (data != "") {

                    $("#span").val(data.span);
                    $("#numcard").val(data.numcard);
                    $("#chan").val(data.chan);
                    $("#idle").val(data.idle);
                    $("#level").val(data.level);
                    $("#call").val(data.call);
                    $("#name").val(data.name);

            }
```